# how can i background-color 50+ divs with separate colors easily | CSS only

Tags: html, css

I am  trying something and it has more than 50 divs and **i want background-color for each div with separate color.**
Is their any way or trick to do it fast **or** i need to do it one by one..

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<style>
box{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 25%; 
  border:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<box></box>
<box></box>
<box></box>
<box></box>
<box></box>
<box></box>
<box></box>
<!--and more box box box...-->

</body>
```

Comment: For loop? What have you tried so far?

Comment: hey.. im not familiar with javascript..please css only

Comment: You should take a look at [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). How you extract/generate colors is up to you. I don't think there's a way to do it with pure CSS. I'll leave that to the CSS experts, though.

Comment: @Nakul If you dont want to use Javascript, then you have to do it manually one by one. Have fun :P

Comment: If CSS only I am afraid you can not do it at all

Comment: You can do it without JS but you will need SASS for example. I can post a snippet if you need

Comment: Why did you tag jquery and javascript then???

Comment: @RononDex why are you not reading the bold text "ony CSS please"

Comment: @Nakul Oh my! Alright let me make clear why we are confused:
First, normally every web developer knows how to use Javascript and also uses it, Stackoverflow is not a place to learn coding, but to ask other programmers for help when you are stuck (after you tried something by yourself).
Second you have tagged javascript and jquery in the question, so when I see your question I see ah, you are interested in Javascript and Jquery. You should read the FAQ of Stackoverflow and familiriasie yourself with web developing techniques. And yet you still accept an answer with JS? Troll level 1000

Comment: @RononDex . someone is not questioning and trying to help a beginner that's why i am accepting that answer

Comment: @Nakul Well again, then you did not understand the purpose of Stack overflow. Of course you will always find some nice persons that will help you even though your question does not meet the requirements for a Stackoverflow question. However as I told you SO is not a place where you should ask questions like this when you are a beginner. There are mostly only profesionals on here and after 1000's question from beginners that could be easily solved by the questioner itstelf by just watching some really basic tutorials or so is frustrating and destroys the purpose of SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaScript.

You could either generate random colors or create an array of colors and pick a color sequentially or randomly.

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
// An array we need to generate a random hex value.
var all = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

// Function that will return a random element from the array 'all'
function rand() {
  return all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)];
}

// Loop through all '.box' elements
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  // Call the function 'rand()' six times to generate a valid hex value(#000000) and
  // assign the new hex value to currently iterated '.box' element's 'backgroundColor'
  box[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + rand() + rand() + rand() + rand() + rand() + rand();
}
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

To give specific colors to all `.box`es you could put the colors in an array and use each color using the `i` variable to pick the color sequentially.

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var colors = ['coral', 'blueviolet', 'burlywood', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'darkgoldenrod', 'olive', 'sienna', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'tomato', 'pink', 'maroon', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'darkslateblue', 'coral', 'blueviolet', 'burlywood', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'darkgoldenrod']

for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is good but _please ans in CSS here is code.._....as per asker.

Comment: what if i want specific color for each one....

Comment: @Nakul - I'll add an example.

Comment: please add some comments so i can understand whats happenning

Answer (score 0):

Used [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) post for color generator:

```js
$('box').each(function() {
  var bg = '#' + (function co(lor){   return (lor +=
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
  && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor); })('');
  $(this).css({'background-color': bg});
});
```

```css
box{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 25%; 
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
<box>box</box>
```